# View doesn't show Controller's data

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have 4 files, View, a Module, a controller and a factory :

**Module : project.module.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.projects', [])
    .config(routeConfig);

/** @ngInject */
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('projects', {
            url: '/projects',
            template : '<ui-view  autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ui-view>',
            abstract: true,
            title: 'Les projets',
            Controller : 'ProjectController',
            sidebarMeta: {
                icon: 'ion-compose',
                order: 250,
            },
.state('projects.add', {
            url: '/add',
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/projects/add/addProject.html',
            title: 'Ajouter un projet',
            sidebarMeta: {
                order: 800,
            },
.state('projects.list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/projects/list/listProjects.html',
            title: 'List',
            sidebarMeta: {
                order: 900,
            },
 });
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/projects','/projects/list');
}

})();
```

**Controller : ProjectController.js**

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.projects')
                .controller('ProjectController', ProjectController);

function ProjectController($state, $stateParams, $log, $scope, projectFactory) {
<!-- Value to show -->
$scope.addMessage = "see ME";
...}
 })();
```

**Factory : projectFactory.js**

```
function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.projects')
  .factory('projectFactory', projectFactory);

function projectFactory($http, $stateParams) {
  var factory = {};
   ....
}})();
```

**View : addProject.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div
            ba-panel
            ba-panel-title="Ajouter un projet"
            ba-panel-class="with-scroll">

        <form name="ProjectForm" ng-submit="setProject()" ng-init="getProjectById()">

            <!-- Value to show -->

            Show me the add message : {{addMessage}}


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="titre">Titre du projet</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titre" placeholder="Titre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-controller="datepickerpopupCtrl">

                <label>Date de début: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></label>
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" datepicker-options="options" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" show-button-bar="false" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                     </span>
                </p>
            </div>
 <section class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <button progress-button="progressFunction()" pb-style="rotate-side-up" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
            </section>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the state is loaded perfectly and everything is working fine but when I try to load a variable from the controller in the View it doesn't show.

And I'm loading the scripts in the index page :

```
<script src="app/pages/projects/projects.modules.js"></script>
<script src="app/pages/projects/projectFactory.js"></script>
<script src="app/pages/projects/ProjectController.js"></script>
<script src="app/pages/projects/add/addProject.html"></script>
```

**P.S:** I have an error and I don't know if it's related or not :

> projects.html:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

***P.S:*** I'm using this [BootsTrap template](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin)

Comment: `<script src="app/pages/projects/add/projects.html"></script>`: that doesn't make sense. An HTML template is not a script. Which variable are you talking about? The view is the view of what?

Comment: I've edited the post, the idea is that my view is not seeing my controller. and to test that I've put a variable `addMessage` in the controller to be shown in the View.

Comment: We have no idea where that view is used. It's not referenced anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: ah sorry forgot to add the state, I added it now

Comment: `Controller : 'ProjectController'` should be `controller : 'ProjectController'`.

Comment: This hurts my heart really, it works...Thank you............

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Is your code working?

Comment: As I said it worked when I changed `Controller` to `controller`